# Prove that there's only 3 normal subgroups in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup such that $|H| = 15$.
And also $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

The question is to show that there are only 3 normal subgroups of order 30 in $G$.

I only know some pretty easy facts from Lagrange's theorem, and don't know how it affects normal subgroups.

Comment: By “only 3” perhaps you mean “at most $3?$ Because the cases when $G$ is abelian, we have only one such normal subgroup.

Comment: Is the statement something like the number of normal or proper subgroups containing $H$?  As the answer below mentions, there can be only one subgroup of order $25$ with the restrictions you mention.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in my question. I mean $|H| = 15$

Comment: So you want normal subgroups of order $15$?  Your question still asks for normal subgroups of order $25$, which now can't occur at all because $\vert G \vert = 60$.

Comment: Of course I'm asking about normal subgroups of order 30. Still don't know why I couldn't fix it with one edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood something about the question.  The conditions you've given tell us that $\vert G \vert = 100$ so that $H$ is a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, which means (since you're told that it's normal) that $H$ is the *unique* subgroup of $G$ of order $25$.

Conversely, if $G$ has $3$ subgroups of order $25$, then they are conjugates of each other and are not normal.

Perhaps you're supposed to show that $G$ has $3$ subgroups of order $50$?

**Edited to respond to corrected question**

There are at least $3$ such subgroups, corresponding to the non-trivial proper subgroups of $G/H$, and those are the only three such subgroups that contain $H$.

Note also that the Sylow subgroups of $H$ are normal in $H$, which means that they're unique in $H$, which means that they're also normal in $G$.  Thus, $H$ is the *unique* subgroup of order $15$ in $G$.

But any order $30$ subgroup of $G$ would have to contain $H$ (because it contains the unique $3$-Sylow and $5$-Sylow subgroups of $G$), so the three subgroups you've already identified are the only three there can be.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missclicked while typing order of $|H|$. I mean 15, alredy fixed.